# DataView filter and returning a string array

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a DataTable and I applied a filter on the DataTable

I have two questions:

1) I want to apply additional filter so that it return only top 10 rows after the filter is applied.

2)  I want to convert a DataView to string Array after the filter is applied

Here is what I did so far:

I am passing a prefix variable as a parameter to the below function:

```
dt = GetNumbers()
    ' filtering in datatabase



    Dim dv As DataView = New DataView(dt)
    dv.RowFilter = "number like '" + prefix + "%'"

     ' I want to return only top 10 rows after the above filter is applied
     ' after this I want to convert the dataview to string array and return that.

    Return strArray
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: dv.ToTable(...).Rows.Cast<System.Data.DataRow>().Take(10)

Comment: What do you mean by a string array, so you want to select one column only ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Function Top10(dt As DataTable, prefix As String) As String()
  Dim dv As New DataView(dt, "number LIKE '" & prefix & "%'", "number ASC", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
  Dim strArray(9) As String
  For i As Integer = 0 To 9
    strArray(i) = CStr(dv.Item(i).Item("number"))
  Next i
  Return strArray
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
dv.ToTable().AsEnumerable().Take(10).Select(x => x.Field<string>("ColumnName")).ToArray();
```